# Where is this CSS file located?

Tags: css

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTu4V.jpg)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US8js.jpg) 

The div "menu-header" (on the images above) has a css rule for the grey background (#56575b). But the rule is coming from a css located... where? It says "admin-ajax....." where the css file source usually stands.
I've tried to change the background with a rule in the standard style.css but the mystery selector has the evil "!important" after...

I'm using a wordpress theme that is just great... Until this happened.

Anyone knows where this css is coming from? Thanks

Comment: More suited to : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add you CSS style as inline attribute with the `!important` like this :

```
style="background:pink !important"
```

The inline style attribute is more important than the file based css ;)

Comment: simple and effective!